# How to load nested json to hive table with two records for below scenario

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please help me to get output as show below for JSON:

```
{ "value":["id":"orien""class":"8to9""properties": {"subscription": 1"year","unit": "appl",}},
{"id": "hyderabad","class": "9to10","properties":{"subscription": "2years","unit": "appl23", }}]}
```

If we write select query like this:

`select id, class,  properties.subscription,properties.unit from table`

Output should be

```
id           class    properties.subscription  properties.unit
orien        8to9     1year                   appl
Hyderabad    9to10    2year                   appl23
```

Comment: have you tried using get_son_object ? see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object for more details